# How to understand this tickdata `askvolume` and `bidvolume` fields?

Tags: tick-data

Here is 1 tick:

> Timestamp,Bid price,Ask price,Bid volume,Ask volume
>
> 20151127 00:05:00:592,1.06057,1.06061,1,1.5

Does `ask volume` 1.5 mean 1.5 million were actually sold or is it just an offer

Another question. Here is some more tickdata:

> 20151127 00:10:35:292,1.06056,1.06058,1.12000000476837,1.5
>
> 20151127 00:10:35:821,1.06056,1.06058,1.12000000476837,1.5
>
> 20151127 00:10:37:284,1.06056,1.06058,1.12000000476837,1.5
>
> 20151127 00:10:37:785,1.06056,1.06058,1.12000000476837,1.5

You can see that the time changes but the best offers do not change. I thought it's supposed to "tick" when there is an update.

Comment: Where does this tick data come from?

Comment: this is from dukascopy

Comment: Don't they provide documentation explaining what their fields mean?

Answer (score 1):

Since this row of data reflects both bid and ask state simultaneously, this row of data represents a quote, not a trade. So the latter is true: it is just an offer.